# Why is $\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} a^{i}i=\frac{a}{(1-a)^{2}}$?

Tags: summation

I saw this series in some mathematical proofs but I couldn't find why $\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} a^{i}i=\frac{a}{(1-a)^{2}}$

Comment: It is not. $$\sum_{i=0}^{\color{red}{+\infty}}i a^i = \frac{a}{(1-a)^2}$$ if $|a|<1$.

Comment: That comes from differentiating with respect to $a$ $$\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty}a^i = \frac{1}{1-a},$$ for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series is as follows :-
$$S=a+2a^2+3a^3+.....+=a[1+2a+3a^2+........]\tag{1.}$$
You can see that the series in the brackets is differentiation of the following series:-
$$S_1=a+a^2+a^3+.........\implies S_1=\frac{a}{1-a}$$
i.e. $$S_1'=\frac{S}{a}\implies \frac{S}{a}=\frac{1}{1-a^2}\implies S=\frac{a}{1-a^2}$$
There we go......

Answer (score 1):

You can start with the standard **finite** evaluation:
$$
1+a+a^2+...+a^n=\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}, \quad a \neq1. \tag1
$$ Then by differentiating $(1)$ we have
$$
1+2a+3a^2+...+na^{n-1}=\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{(1-a)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)a^{n}}{1-a}, \quad |a|<1, \tag2
$$ multiplying by $a$ and by making $n \to +\infty$ in $(2)$, **using $|a|<1$**, gives

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} na^n=\frac{a}{(1-a)^2}. \tag3
$$

Comment: Why did you get differential in part (2)?

Comment: @sajjad When one differentiates $a^n$ then one obtains $n a^{n-1}$, it gives the factor $n$. That's why I did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na^ii$, then $aS(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^na^{i+1}i$ and
\begin{align}
(1-a)S
&=a+a^2+\cdots+a^n+na^{n+1}\\
&=\frac{a-a^{n+1}}{1-a}+na^{n+1}\\
&=\frac{a-a^{n+1}+(1-a)na^{n+1}}{1-a}.
\end{align}
So we conclude that 
$$s(n)=\frac{a-a^{n+1}+(1-a)na^{n+1}}{(1-a)^2}\quad\mbox{for }n\in\mathbb{N},$$
and then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}s(n)=\frac{a}{(1-a)^2}$ because
$-1<a<1$.